# Addresses keep expanding with wrong name in Gmail

Tags: gmail

A colleague uses Gmail, and since a while some addresses he uses expand automatically into strange names. This could very well be the result of a copy & paste action into the address field, but it's impossible to know how it happened.

Take the following example:

- User types in or pastes: info@xyz.test
- On pressing enter or moving the cursor to another field, this address expands into something like this:

```
"XYZ, PQR <info@pqr.test, info@mnop.test" <info@xyz.test>
```

This is confusing because it looks like the mail is send to three addresses (xyz, pqr and mnop), but (probably) only xyz is used. I can't test this as I can't bother these people with this problem. XYZ will notice the strange format when receiving the mail, and that is problematic considering the relationship between these three.

In the contacts I could find several addresses that were formatted like this, and I could remove them. They are fixed. Some addresses are still behaving like this, and I don't know how to fix it.

I've tried a different browser, cleared all cookies, and that doesn't help.

**Questions**

- Is this a history problem?
- How can I remove or edit this address?

Comment: It seems like the display names of these contacts are corrupted. In the Contacts list, hover over such a contact and click the icon of "Edit contact" (a pen). If you can't see the corruption, click the link of "Show more".

Answer (score 0):

I think your contact names are incorrect, because the text in quotation marks ("XYZ, PQR info@pqr.test, info@mnop.test") is just random text, and the text in brackets (info@xyz.test) is the email.

**To Change The Text:**

- Go to https://contacts.google.com/
- Search For "info@xyz.test" (or another email)
- Highlight the contact, and click the edit button (pencil)
- Change The First Name / Last Name to what you would like to call the person/company

**To Delete The Text:**

- Go to https://contacts.google.com/
- Search For "info@xyz.test" (or another email)
- Click on the Contact
- Click The 3 Dots, and click "Delete"
- Click Delete